# CakePHP 3.6 TreeBehavior end DataTables RowReorder not saving new position

Tags: cakephp, tree, save, row

I need to combine the Treebehavior (with parent_id, lft and rght fields) with DataTables Row Reorder. I can drag and drop the rows but the new positions are not saved. How should I save the new position of the 'dragged' item?

In my Controller I have:

```
    public function index($archived = 0)
{
    // Row Reorder
    $groups = TableRegistry::get('Groups');
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')):
        $this->autoRender = false;
        if (!empty($this->request->data)):
            $oldPosition = $this->request->data['oldPos'];
            $newPosition = $this->request->data['newPos'];
            $nodeId = $this->request->data['id'];

            $diff = abs($oldPosition - $newPosition);

            $node = $groups->get($nodeId);
            for ($i=1;$i<=$diff;$i++):
                if ($oldPosition > $newPosition):
                    $groups->moveUp($node);
                else:
                    $groups->moveDown($node);
                endif;
            endfor;
        endif;
    endif;
    // set archived condition
    if ($this->request->getQuery('archived')):
        $conditions['Groups.archived'] = $this->request->getQuery('archived');
        if ($this->request->getQuery('archived') == 1):
            $this->set('switch_background_color', SWITCH_ARCHIVE_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        endif;
    else:
        $conditions['Groups.archived'] = 0;
    endif;
    $groups = $this->Groups->find('all', [
        'conditions' => $conditions,
        'order' => ['Groups.lft' => 'ASC']
    ]);
    if (empty($groups)):
        $this->Flash->error(__('No {0} yet!', __('Groups')) . ' ' . __('Please add one.'), ['params' => ['class' => 'warning', 'escape' => false]]);
        $this->redirect(['action' => 'add']);
    endif;
    // count archived
    $archived = $this->Groups->find('all', [
        'conditions' => ['Groups.archived' => 1]
    ]);
    $count_archived = $archived->count();
    $this->set(compact('groups', 'count_archived'));
}
```

And in my index-view I have:

```
<table id="datatable-<?= $controller ?>">
    ...
</table>

<?= $this->Html->scriptStart(['block' => 'scriptBottom']) ?>
    var table = $('#datatable-<?= $controller ?>').DataTable({
        rowReorder: true,
        paging: false,
        columnDefs: [
            {targets: 0, visible: false},
            {targets: 1, visible: false},
            {targets: 2, orderable: false},
            {targets: 3, orderable: false},
            {targets: 4, orderable: false},
            {targets: 5, orderable: false},
            {targets: 6, orderable: false}
        ]
    });

    table.on('row-reorder', function (e, diff, edit){
        var oldPos = "";
        var newPos = "";
        var group_id = edit.triggerRow.data()[1];

        for (var i=0, ien=diff.length; i < ien; i++){
            var rowData = table.row(diff[i].node).data();
            if (edit.triggerRow.data()[1] == rowData[1]){
                oldPos = parseInt(diff[i].oldPosition + 1);
                newPos = parseInt(diff[i].newPosition + 1);
            }
        }

        jQuery.ajax({
            url     :   'groups',
            type    :   'POST',
            data    :    {'id':group_id,"oldPos":oldPos,"newPos":newPos},
            success: function(res){

            }
        });
    });

    $('div.dataTables_filter input').focus();
<?= $this->Html->scriptEnd() ?>
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to add to save the new position of the 'dragged' item?

Comment: You may want to explain how exactly you expect your code to work, and add some debugging information (what data is being received, what values are being calculated, what do the `moveUp/Down` calls return, etc...) that shows what exactly currently happens ("_doesn't work_" is not a  sufficient problem description).

Comment: @ndm As mentioned in the question: I can drag and drop and everything looks fine but when I refresh the page the rows are at their initial position again so the new positions (lft and rght values) are not saved by the TreeBehaviour. I'm sorry but I'm not good in javascript and I don't know where to get the js debugging info you're referring to.

Comment: On the JS side you can use `console.log()`, on the CakePHP side you can use [**response headers**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#setting-headers), [**logging**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#writing-to-logs), or a proper debugger like xdebug.